# SQL select involving multiple tables

Tags: sql, syntax

In my SQL database, I have a CLIENTS table with an ID column.
I have an APPOINTMENTS table containing ID, CLIENTID (which is the ID from the CLIENTS table), and STATUS.

Is there a way to write one SELECT statement that will find the client ID of the client whose STATUS='NO SHOW' the most often? Is there a way to display all clients and ORDER BY how often that an appointment exists where STATUS='NO SHOW'?

Comment: Can you post your input data and expected results? Also which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @skawt - Can you post, what you have tried as of yet ? your requirement is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to count the number of appointments, and order by that list. Beyond that you can do what you want.

```
select * from (
    select C.ID, count(*) as NoShow 
    from CLIENTS  C
    INNER JOIN APPOINEMENTS A ON A.CLIENTID = C.ID
    WHERE STATUS='NO SHOW'
    group by c.ID
) q order by NoShow desc
```

Comment: The JOIN is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes you are correct @erwin. Was thinking there are probably more columns than the abridged example but for the exact question you are right.

Comment: I needed to add A.STATUS='NO SHOW' because my CLIENTS table also contains a STATUS column, and it didn't work with the lower case "c" but "group by C.ID" worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the unnecessary join from TomC's answer :

```
select * from (
    select CLIENTID, count(*) as NoShow 
    from APPOINTMENTS 
    WHERE STATUS='NO SHOW'
    group by CLIENTID
) q order by NoShow desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select C.ID,A.STATUS from CLIENTS  C
INNER JOIN APPOINEMENTS A ON A.CLIENTID = C.ID
WHERE STATUS='NO SHOW'
```

Do you mean like this ? Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want "the most often", then you want to limit the result to one row.  The ANSI/ISO SQL construct is `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
select CLIENTID
from APPOINTMENTS 
where STATUS = 'NO SHOW'
group by CLIENTID
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Some databases use `limit` or `select top (1)` instead of `fetch first`.